# Provider com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.CertificateBasedHttpClientFactory not a subtype

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

In [SAP Cloud SDK FAQ](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/frequently-asked-questions) page, there is a QA about I'm Observing a DefaultHttpClientFactory not a subtype Exception, now I encountered a similar error Provider com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.CertificateBasedHttpClientFactory not a subtype, however I could not exclude connectivity-scp-cf since this is mandatory?
Any hints how to solve this error?

```
Caused by: com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.cf.auth.TokenFactory$GetTokenException: Could not get ClientCredentialsGrantAccessToken
at com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.cf.auth.TokenFactory.getClientCredentialsGrantAccessToken(TokenFactory.java:61)
at com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.cf.destination.ConnectivityConfigurationCF.getConfiguration(ConnectivityConfigurationCF.java:72)
... 92 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/cloud/security/client/HttpClientFactory : cannot initialize class because prior initialization attempt failed
at com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.cf.auth.TokenFactory.executeTokenExchange(TokenFactory.java:94)
at com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.cf.auth.TokenFactory.getClientCredentialsGrantAccessToken(TokenFactory.java:57)
... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sap.cloud.security.client.HttpClientFactory: Provider com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.CertificateBasedHttpClientFactory not a subtype

Comment: If anyone hit the same error, please use OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials to access the API on BTP Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 1):

Interface type `com.sap.cloud.security.client.HttpClientFactory` is part of dependency `com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa:token-client`.

When using *SAP Java Buildpack* (e.g. for JCo), please make sure to give this dependency a `provided` scope. Otherwise you'll be experiencing class loading issues like in your current case. For further errors, please attach your `mvn dependency:tree`.